# Do hibernate stores query result in Persistence context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

Does Hibernate stores the data fetched from `Query` in `persistence context`, if yes then `persistenceContext` will flooded with objects and may result in `OutOfMemoryError?` Am I correct with my assumption, if yes then what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, all entities retrieved by a query are stored in persistence context - you may modify them and they will be automatically persisted without calling `EntityManager.persist()`.

You may clear persistnce context by calling `EntityManager.clear()` - this will detach all entities. If you don't hold reference to them, they will be eventually garbage collected.

However, in order to optimize memory consumption, it is best to avoid creating so many entities in the first place. If you need only some fields from the entities, it is better to build your query so that it retrieves plain objects instead of queries, by constructor mapping. See example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
@Id
private Long id;

private String name;
}

// this is not an entity, but plain object with constructor accepting String name
package mypackage;
public class PersonName {
  private String name;
  public PersonName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And following query will return list of PersonName objects - plain Java objects which are not stored in persistence context:

```
select NEW mypackage.PersonName(p.name) from Person p
```